# Django. Trouble logging in to facebook "rediredt failed because..."

Tags: facebook, authentication

I've been stuck in this issue for two days now and nothing. I successfully setup Google sign in and it works. Every time I try with facebook, I get the following error:

[image]

```
    SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
        'SCOPE': [
            'profile',
            'email',
        ],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {
            'access_type': 'online',
        }
    }
}
\
     {
    'facebook': {
        'METHOD': 'oauth2',
        # 'SDK_URL': '//connect.facebook.net/{locale}/sdk.js',
        'SCOPE': ['email', 'public_profile'],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {'auth_type': 'reauthenticate'},
        'INIT_PARAMS': {'cookie': True},
        'FIELDS': [
            'id',
            "email"
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'middle_name',
            'name',
            'name_format',
            'picture',
            'short_name'
        ],
        'EXCHANGE_TOKEN': True,
        'LOCALE_FUNC': 'path.to.callable',
        'VERIFIED_EMAIL': False,
        'VERSION': 'v13.0',
        'GRAPH_API_URL': 'https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0',
    }
}


ACCOUNT_DEFAULT_HTTP_PROTOCOL="https"
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
```

[image]

Client ID and secret has been added in admin. If i remove the http method allowed, I get a different error mentioning "You can't get an access token or login to this app from an insecure page. Try re-loading the page as https://"

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is the actual value of the `redirect_uri` parameter in your login dialog URL?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know where to find the redirect_uri parameter (relatively new at this)

Comment: Check what the browser address bar contains, on the page where you see that error. That URL should include the `redirect_uri` parameter.

Comment: Ah yes, I tried a few days ago and now again copying and pasting the decoded uri into the valid oauth settings and nothing... I copied over this essentially "https://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/facebook/login/callback/&scope=email&response_type=code&state=nYwI9DveeCwg"

Comment: `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` aren't the same thing here, from Facebook's perspective. The actual value used in your login dialog call, must be entered into the app settings. I don't think they accept IP addresses, so you'll need to figure out how to make your system use localhost instead.

Comment: This was the answer. Thanks! It worked after changing to local host and using python manage.py runserver localhost:8000.